# Как поменять содержимое двух массивов местами друг с другом

Tags: php, массивы

столкнулся с проблемой что не могу поменять содержимое двух массивов местами, чтобы например в массиве А хранилась информация из массива Б и наоборот.

```
    <?php

$n = trim($_POST['number']);
$a = array();
$b = array();
$c = array();
$d = array();

    echo "Массив A:  <br>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $c[]=$a[] = rand(-10, 10);
        $d[]=$b[] = rand(-10, 10);

        print $a[$i];
        print" ";
    }
    echo "<br>Массив Б:  <br>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        print $b[$i];
        print" ";
    }


    echo "<br>измененный массив А:  <br>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $a[$i]=$b[$i];
        print $a[$i];
        print" ";
        }
echo "<br>измененный массив Б:  <br>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $c[$i]=$b[$i];
    print $b[$i];
    print" ";
}
?>
<form method="post">

    <label>кол-во елементов в масиве:<? echo " $n " ?>
        <input type="text" name="number">
    </label><br>
    <button>submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Самый логичный вопрос: зачем?))

Comment: нельзя просто сделать `$c = $b; $b = $a; $a=$c;` ? и зачем тут вообще `$d` у вас, и где собственно вы меняете `$b` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могу придумать зачем это в целом нужно, но если надо, то по старому стандарту обмена:

```
$a= [1,2,3];
$b= [7,8,9];
$c = [];

$c = $a;
$a = $b;
$b = $c;
```

---

либо

```
$a= [1,2,3];
$b= [7,8,9];

list($a, $b) = [$b, $a]; // PHP 7.1: [$a, $b] = [$b, $a];
```